# Capture edited rows only - standalone script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a script to read the incoming rows to a google sheet and compare a cell in each row to store matches and transfer to another sheet. Right now there are over 40k rows and the efficiency of the script is very slow. Any help with the matter would be appreciated and rewarded with a accepted answer. I have attached the code below for reference.

```
function checkRecord() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id"),
      srctrg0   = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
      srctrg1   = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
      srctrg2   = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
      srctrg3   = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
      target1   = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
      s0Range   = srctrg0.getDataRange(), 
      s1Range   = srctrg1.getDataRange(), 
      s2Range   = srctrg2.getDataRange(),
      s3Range   = srctrg3.getDataRange(),
      tRange    = target1.getDataRange(),
      stValues0 = s0Range.getValues(),
      s0        = stValues0.length,
      stValues1 = s1Range.getValues(),
      s1        = stValues1.length,
      stValues2 = s2Range.getValues(),
      s2        = stValues2.length,
      stValues3 = s3Range.getValues(),
      s3        = stValues3.length,
      tValues   = tRange.getValues(),
      t         = tValues.length;
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "yyyy.MM.dd")
  Logger.log(date);
  // Export source to master logs
  for(i = 0; i < tValues.length; i++){ 
    if(date == tValues[i][2])
    {
      Logger.log(tValues[i] + "\n" + "We have a winner");
    }      
    for(i = 1; i < stValues0.length; i++){
      if(false)
      {
        Logger.log(stValues0[i] + "\n");
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < stValues1.length; i++){
      if(false)
      {
        Logger.log(stValues1[i] + "\n");
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < stValues2.length; i++){
      if(false)
      {
        Logger.log(stValues2[i] + "\n");
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < stValues3.length; i++){
      if(false)
      {
        Logger.log(stValues3[i] + "\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Accepting a valid answer is a courtesy, not a reward.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but any suggestions to a solutions would be even more appreciated

Comment: You are resetting your loop counter(`i`) at every sub-loop in your enclosing `for()`, so when you return to the top `i` has the last value assigned in the last loop (which may be > `tValues.length`) - this probably isn't what you want to do.  Also, some insight into why you're scanning every row of every sheet would be helpful (i.e. what is your actual test in `if(false)`?)